# Concatenate words in a string into a single word string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on C# application and I've got a string variable that has more than one word. What I need is to read from it, all the words, and tranform them into one, with no spaces.

String example = `"One Two Three Four"`

String that I want = `"OneTwoThreeFour"`

Is there a function in C# that does this?

Comment: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace()` ?

Comment: Why has my post been voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String concatenatedString = example.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do it;

```
word = word.Replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String example = "One Two Three Four";
string str = example.Replace(" ",string.Empty);
```